# Is an Action card resolved before or after an initiated clash?

Tags: inis

When an Action card initiates a clash, is this Action card resolved

- when the clash ends, or
- before the clash begins?

Background: The red card *Lug Samildanach* allows to take an Action card to your hand after it has been resolved. If player A plays an Action card that initiates a clash, and player B plays *Lug Samildanach*, can B use A’s Action card in this clash?

Comment: What is the exact text on the Lug Samildanch card?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, the action card is resolved **when the clash ends.**

This is not made explicit in the rules, but on p. 7 of the rule book it says (under "Play a Season Card"): "The player plays the card, resolves the indicated effect, and then discards that card." This would mean that everything triggered by the Action Card (such as a clash) is resolved before it is discarded, and thus, by association, that an Action Card is only fully resolved after all its effects have been resolved.